# Ctrl-C'ed a process but it kept running, don't see it running in the background

Tags: bash, background-process

I Ctrl-C'ed a build job I was running in my bash shell. It continued to run in the background and print output to the stdout, however according to `jobs -l` no background job was running. Do we know what could've happened and how could I determine+fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The process had likely dumped a lot of output to the terminal, which was simply still being spooled out to the screen after you sent the interrupt.